# Disable slide menu [drawer] on specific pages in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, navigation, navigation-drawer

I am still a beginner.

I am developing an app which contains a slide menu [drawer].

I want to disable that drawer on a few pages.

In my app, I created two StackNavigator [first- HomeNavigator1, second - HomeNavigator]

```
const HomeNavigator1 = createStackNavigator({

  Start: {
      screen: StartScreen
    },

    Login: {
      screen: LoginScreen
    },
    Register: {
      screen: RegisterScreen
    },
    ForgetPass: {
      screen: ForgetPassScreen
    },

});

const HomeNavigator = createStackNavigator(

{ 
  HomeScreen: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    headerLeft: leftIcon(navigation, 'md-menu')
  })
  },
  WorkoutsScreen: {
    screen: WorkoutsScreen
  },
}, navigationOptions

);
```

In the end, I created DrawerNavigator [combine that 2 stack navigator here]

```
const RootStack = createDrawerNavigator({

  Start:
  {
    screen:HomeNavigator1,
  },
  Home: 
  {
    screen: HomeNavigator,
  }
}, 
//created one other file named SideMenu which contains items of drawer menu
{
  contentComponent: SideMenu,
  drawerWidth: width * .7,
  drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
  drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
  drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle',
}

);
```

**Note:** this whole code in the single file

**My problem or question**

How can I disable the slide menu [drawer] for HomeNavigator1 [for 4 screens Start, login, register and forgetpass]?

Please guide and help me to solve this problem.

**Thank you for contributing your precious time**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the gesture from your route.

```
Start:
  {
    screen:HomeNavigator1,
    navigationOptions: {
        gesturesEnabled: false,
    }
  },
```

Or to your screens:

```
Login: {
      screen: LoginScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
            gesturesEnabled: false,
      }
    }
```

But this is not the best way to fix this.